# Save Gmail subjects as a text file?

Tags: gmail

I'm receiving some kinds of automated job completion notification by email.
Thus it is hard to manage hundreds of email, so I'd like to automate it.

So, is it possible to save all or unread emails' subjects in a text, CSV, or Excel file?

Comment: What operating systems can you use? Is Perl or Python or Ruby available?

Comment: @grawity Windows 10. I wondered if there is a simple solution and I don't want to use complex programming language.

Comment: Using a programming language doesn't have to be complex. You certainly aren't going to find anything simpler. You can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) with the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) from your Google Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use web scraping and Windows task scheduler.

First, write a code to do the following.

1. Log in to your Gmail account.
2. Collect your e-mail subjects using Python Selenium library

Do the above tasks repeatedly using Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do something with [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com).

1. Create a Gmail trigger, either all new messages or new messages that meet some search criteria
2. Create an action to add a line to a Google Sheet. You would probably want the date/time, sender, and the subject

[This recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/482430-save-mail-subjects-to-google-sheet) should give you an idea of what you can do (or you can simply modify this recipe for your own purposes).